# JavaScript async/await function performance improvement

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a simple async/await function which gets data from a firebase endpoint. I would like to know if there is any room for improvement performance wise.

```
async function getDataById(id) {
  const snapshot = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("collection")
    .where("id", "==", id)
    .get();
  const documents = [];
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    documents.push(doc.data());
  });
  return documents;
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm no firebase expert, but from what I understand from this code, there are no glaring issues. Did you have any specific concerns with this function that is making you think there might be a performance issue going on?